# Shadowbox and Google Analytics Download Script Not Working

Tags: google-analytics, shadowbox

I have had Shadowbox running on my site for a long time. Requirements want us to track Downloads within Google Analytics. After installing the following script, Shadowbox now opens in the same window. There's a conflict between the two scripts, and I'm kind of stumped.

Here's the tracking Downloads script that was installed:

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var filetypes = /\.(zip|exe|dmg|pdf|doc.*|xls.*|ppt.*|mp3|txt|rar|wma|mov|avi|wmv|flv|wav)$/i;
    var baseHref = '';
    if (jQuery('base').attr('href') != undefined) baseHref = jQuery('base').attr('href');

jQuery('a').on('click', function(event) {
  var el = jQuery(this);
  var track = true;
  var href = (typeof(el.attr('href')) != 'undefined' ) ? el.attr('href') :"";
  var isThisDomain = href.match(document.domain.split('.').reverse()[1] + '.' + document.domain.split('.').reverse()[0]);
  if (!href.match(/^javascript:/i)) {
    var elEv = []; elEv.value=0, elEv.non_i=false;
    if (href.match(/^mailto\:/i)) {
      elEv.category = "email";
      elEv.action = "click";
      elEv.label = href.replace(/^mailto\:/i, '');
      elEv.loc = href;
    }
    else if (href.match(filetypes)) {
      var extension = (/[.]/.exec(href)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(href) : undefined;
      elEv.category = "download";
      elEv.action = "click-" + extension[0];
      elEv.label = href.replace(/ /g,"-");
      elEv.loc = baseHref + href;
    }
    else if (href.match(/^https?\:/i) && !isThisDomain) {
      elEv.category = "external";
      elEv.action = "click";
      elEv.label = href.replace(/^https?\:\/\//i, '');
      elEv.non_i = true;
      elEv.loc = href;
    }
    else if (href.match(/^tel\:/i)) {
      elEv.category = "telephone";
      elEv.action = "click";
      elEv.label = href.replace(/^tel\:/i, '');
      elEv.loc = href;
    }
    else track = false;

    if (track) {
      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', elEv.category.toLowerCase(), elEv.action.toLowerCase(), elEv.label.toLowerCase(), elEv.value, elEv.non_i]);
      if ( el.attr('target') == undefined || el.attr('target').toLowerCase() != '_blank') {
        setTimeout(function() { location.href = elEv.loc; }, 400);
        return false;
  }
}
  }
});
});
}
```

Comment: I suggest you include the error/s conflicts you are getting on screen

Comment: Can you include a sample link

Comment: Hi, Micallef. Here's a link to the site: [link](http://www.merge.com) . If you click on the "WATCH NOW" link under Cardiology, you'll see the video open in the same window, when it should be a new, small window. (And thanks for your help!!!)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you keep the download and tracking separately.

If you use the following tracking code for tracking clicks within [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com.mt/analytics/):

```
function trackOutboundLink(link, category, action, opt_label) { // google analytics tracking
    try { 
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category , action, opt_label]); 
    } catch(err){}

    if (link.target == '_blank')
        window.open(link.href);
     else {
        setTimeout(function() {
        document.location.href = link.href;
        }, 100);
     }
}
```

then use in the `<a></a>`

```
<a onclick="trackOutboundLink(this, 'CategoryName', 'ActionName', 'LabelName'); return false;" href="whatever.html" target="_blank">External Website Name</a>
```

where `CategoryName`, `ActionName` and `LabelName` can be anything you want and will show in Analytics. Tihs can be kicked off before the download script kicks off.

Comment: Hi! Thank you SO much for your answer. So if I'm understanding this correctly, that would mean I would have to go back in to all of our PDF a href's and tag them individually, and we have HUNDREDS! I was hoping not to have to do that.

Comment: both scripts are in fact based on the same concept... what errors are you getting?

Comment: My Shadowbox contains a link that should open a video link in a new, smaller window, and since I installed the script above, it just opens it up in the same window, instead of a small, custom window.

Comment: there must be conflict (possible same variables) between the 2 scripts... you will need to troubleshoot the code until you identify the problematic function.

Comment: Yeah, I feel like it's the setTimeout that's being a punk, and not playing nicely, but unfortunately, I don't have the knowledge to debug it from there! :(

Comment: I found this which might help - http://www.saltedstone.com/2012/10/google-analytics-event-tracking/